# Jquery: onclick event added to dynamically created <li> while parsing JSON is giving error when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making an `ajax` `get` call for JSON data and displaying a list by dynamically creating `li` elements.

JSON data is in the format:

```
[
  {"name":"Obj1", "id":"1"},
  {"name":"Obj2", "id":"2"},
  {"name":"Obj3", "id":"3"},
  ......
]
```

The html where I am appending `li` is:

```
<div id="lists">
  <ul id="bullets"></ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to create an `onclick` event on `li` which calls a function which takes the `JSON Obj: id`. Here's how am doing this:

```
$.ajax({ 
  type: 'GET', 
  url: URL, 
  data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
  success: function (data) { 
    $.each(data.slice(2), function(index, element) {

        $('#bullets').append('<li id="demo" onclick="loadCards(\"' + element.id + '\")">' + element.name + '</li>');

    });
  }
});
```

Now, this displays the list correctly but as I click on the name, i get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input:  loadCards(
```

HTML generated looks like this:

```
<li id="demo" onclick="loadCards(" 1")"="">PB Dashboard</li>
```

`1` is the object id in above JSON but am not sure why is this html? Not able to resolve this.

Is there a way to add `anchor` tags in `li` and then perform click?

Comment: side note, id="demo", will not be unique.

Comment: Does not need to be unique. I can remove it.

Comment: Why hasn't anyone questioned the `=""` in `onclick="loadCards(" 1")"=""` Is this normal? Never seen anything like it.

Comment: Ya. That is fixed after removing the `\` but error remains same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this

```
$('#bullets').append('<li id="demo" onclick="loadCards(\'' + element.id + '\')">' + element.name + '</li>');
```

As exemplified by this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mubsf7ed/14/):

Comment: @roger_that Nice would you mind accepting this as the answer? If that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

There may not be any need the slash

```
$('#bullets').append('<li id="demo"'+index+'"
                      onclick="loadCards("' + element.id + '")">' + 
                      element.name + '</li>');
```

Comment: Tried. HTML changed to `<li id="demo" onclick="loadCards(" 5b5aa88cb8f7d903b6091903")"="">PB Dashboard</li>`  but `onclick` shows the same error.

Comment: How does the dom look like after making this change

Comment: Also how `5b5aa88cb8f7d903b6091903` is coming?, I do not see this value in the response

Comment: How can you see the response when you don't have the URL?

Comment: DOM is as it should be. Multiple `li` appended to the existing `ul`

Comment: I think the json you shared is the response . isn't?

Comment: Ah. Edited the id.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `'&quot;'` entity inside `loadCards` will work and avoid to conflict with start `"` of `onclick`.

**Here is the snippet:**

```js
var jsonData=[
  {"name":"Obj1", "id":"1"},
  {"name":"Obj2", "id":"2"},
  {"name":"Obj3", "id":"3"},
 
]
function myFunction(){
$.each(jsonData, function (key, element) {
   $('#bullets').append('<li id="demo" onclick="loadCards(&quot;' + element.id + '&quot;)">' + element.name + '</li>');

   
})
}

function loadCards(idd){
alert(idd);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lists">
  <ul id="bullets"></ul>
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also avoid using the `onclick` property and bind the click event direct to the `li` tag

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const bulletsElement = $('#bullets');

  bulletsElement.on('click', 'li[data-load-card]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const cardId = $(this).data('load-card');
    alert("Card ID: " + cardId);
  });

  const dataFromServer = [{
      "name": "Obj1",
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Obj2",
      "id": "2"
    },
    {
      "name": "Obj3",
      "id": "3"
    }
  ];

  $.each(dataFromServer, function(index, element) {
    bulletsElement.append('<li data-load-card="' + element.id + '">' + element.name + '</li>');
    //or using ES6 Template Literals:
    //bulletsElement.append(`<li data-load-card="${element.id}">${element.name}</li>`);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lists">
  <ul id="bullets"></ul>
</div>
```